# How to use variables in shell?

Tags: linux

Having a simple script like this, which should convert minutes to seconds

```
#!bin/bash
echo 'input_minutes'
read x
time="expr $x '*' 60"
echo $time
```

When run after entering a number (5), it outputs an expression `"expr $x '*' 60"` instead of a product(300). What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't execute the expression, instead you created a string.
Try it like this:

```
time=$(expr $x '*' 60)
```